# How to connect cat. 5e cables that are put in the wall?

Tags: networking, router, cable

I bought a new apartment and I would like to have wired network available in 4 different rooms. Let's call them LR (living room) and BR[1-3] (bedrooms).

Ideally I would like to have a connection between each 2 sockets I choose. So, e.g. if I connect a computer to a socket in BR1 and another computer in BR3 then they should be on the same wired network.

How I plan to use it currently is:
- Modem/Router/Wifi/TV/Audio in LR
- One computer in BR1
- One computer in BR2

I plan to have one RJ-45 socket in each room and would like to connect computers to sockets in BR1 and BR2. I want them to have the Internet access through the Modem/Router which would be connected to a socket in LR.

How can I achieve that? Can I have one socket in LR or should I have 3 sockets there for each BRx?

Answer (score 2):

You will need some sort of switch inside the wall to make that happen.

1 Socket per BRx is fine, and you need at least a 4-port switch inside the wall, where each wall socket is connected to that switch.

BR1-2-3 each connected to port 1,2,3 on the switch, and LR connected to port 0 (or 4).

Then the LR port is connected to your Modem/Router/WiFi module that provides internet access (which may have more than 1 port, and wifi access). The TV in your Living Room can then either access internet (if needed) via either cable (directly to your Modem/Router), or via WiFi.

```
                    +---------------------------+
                    |               Living Room |
+---+   +-------+   | +--------+                |
|BR1+---+       |   | | Modem  |                |
+---+   |       +---+-+ Router |                |
        | 4port |   | | WiFi   |                |
+---+   | switch|   | | 1/4port|                |
|BR2+---+  or   |   | +--------+                |
+---+   | more  |   |                           |
        | inside|   |                           |
+---+   | wall  |   |  +--+                     |
|BR3+---+       |   |  |TV|                     |
+---+   +-------+   |  +--+                     |
                    +---------------------------+
```

If you do not want to embed a switch inside the wall, then your Living Room will need 3 out-socket / 3 cables coming out from a hole for the cables from your Bedrooms and those cables can go directly into your Modem/Router/WiFi port (so you don't need to make an Ethernet Jack on the Living Room wall)

```
           +---------------------------+
           |               Living Room |
+---+      | +--------+                |
|BR1+--------+ Modem  |                |
+---+  +-----+ Router |                |
+---+  | +---+ WiFi   |                |
|BR2+--+ | | +--------+                |
+---+    | |                           |
+---+    | |                           |
|BR3+----+ |                           |
+---+      |  +--+                     |
           |  |TV|                     |
           |  +--+                     |
           +---------------------------+
```

ASCII art courtesy of http://asciiflow.com

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful! What would you suggest? Is switch inside a wall a common thing to implement in private flats? Is it a normal switch that is connected to a power outlet or is it some special kind of switch that you just hide in the wall?

Comment: Just your normal 4-port (or more) switch that you just hide inside the wall. Whether it is common or not - is really up to you as I don't know how far you want to hole up / wire up your apartment. Personally I am not a builder so I will never break the wall  - and put cabling - I won't be able to make it nice and smooth again. I will either run cable outside, or rely heavily on wireless. There are some wireless access points that has strong signal power, or if your apartment is very thick walled, or considerably wide, a wireless repeater can be used to extend range.

Comment: I know about wireless and I have no problems with extending the signal. I use it for almost everything, except for gaming, so I want to have normal cat 5e cables. I tried PLC, but the connection wasn't stable and I would very often get lags...

Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Putting a switch in the wall is pretty stupid. It needs power. It can't get rid of it's heat (think 20-30W and always on, heat will build up). If it breaks or if you want to replace it with a faster switch you will have to break the wall open again. The normal thing to do is install a small patch-panel somewhere close to the router from which you will run individual cables to each room. Place the small switch directly at the patch-panel and run 1 cable to the router. Or have the router double up as that switch.

Comment: One more question. Let's assume I go for 3 sockets in BRx and 3 sockets in LR for each bedroom. Now let's say I want to connect BR1 and BR3 directly. Can I connect computers in BR1 and BR3 to their sockets and make a loop between their respective sockets in LR to achieve that?

Comment: Technically yes you can. It is usually when you need a crossover cable (although most newer network card doesn't need crossover cable) - but it adds to the complexity (and also means you have to unplug cables). If you simply leave all the BR cables connected to the switch/router (as per @Tonny suggestion) - all connected computer (or TV) can all talk to each other as they are all in the same network.

Comment: Sure thing, that's the plan. I was just asking theoretically, thanks!